# Sum up with R base

Tags: r, statistics

Sorry, that I didn't wrote the sum function in latex. I tried $$ but that didn't work...

I am a beginner in R and I want to sum up:

```
Sum from i=0 to n by 1.054^i
```

I reserached the `sum()` function in R. However, it seems to me that is only can just add elements and not include an index or something.

So my question is: Can I solve that with a simple sum function or do I have to use a for loop for example?

I really appreciate your answer!

**UPDATE**

Here is a link to my sum(sorry that I cannot post it, but I need more reputation :([link](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Csum%20%5Climits_%7Bi=0%7D%5En%201.054%5Ei) )

Comment: @eddi Thank you very much for your answer! Please post it as a reply and I will accept it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In R most operations are vectorized, it requires changing the mindset a bit from other languages and for this question the answer is rather than looping, you simply do the entire operation on your sequence of numbers "at once":

```
sum(1.054^(0:n))
```